# Isolated points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Every point $x \in S \subset\Bbb R$ is isolated.

1) $S$ is closed?

2) $S$ doesn't have any limit point?

My attempt: by definition any isolated point is boundary point, and cannot be limit point. The only option left is that limit point $\notin S$. Suppose there is at least one such point. Then, any neighborhood of limit point contains at least one point from $S$, i.e. isolated point. On the other hand, the neighborhood of isolated point should not contain any other point. Contradiction. Thus, (2) is true.

$S$ may be called closed iff $S$ contains all its boundary points. It already contains all its isolated points. And, any boundary point, that is not isolated, must be a limit one. But true (2) precludes this. So, (1) is true.

Was the proof correct?

Comment: What about $S=\{1/n :n=1,2, 3,\ldots\,\}$?

Comment: "the neighborhood of isolated point should not contain any other point." This is incorrect. *Some* nhood of an isolated point of $S$ contains no other point of $S$. This nhood won't be an nhood of the limit point.